# Trying to post to facebook page with app but get "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to write a script that will post an update to a facebook page timeline. I created an app and created a key for the app. I am using the code below:

```
require_once HOME_PATH . '/include/facebook/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
  'scope' => 'publish_stream',
));

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$attachment = array(
  'access_token' => $access_token,
  'message' => 'this is my message',
  'name' => 'name',
  'link' => ROOT_URL . $blog_data['url'] . '.htm',
  'caption' => $blog_data['title'],
  'description' => $blog_data['title'],
);
if ($image = get_first_image($blog_data['body'])) {
  $attachment['picture'] = $image;
}
$facebook->api(FACEBOOK_BLOG_PAGE . '/feed', 'post', $attachment);
```

i think this key is connected to the app and not to my user, so it sounds like i would have to grant the permission within facebook, but i have seen some other posts telling me that i need to do this in code. The examples aren't very clear.

I know similar questions have been asked but i haven't seen any clear answers yet. Can anyone please clarify this?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've done the OAuth dance. You need to do this.

Comment: so it has to be authorized to my user directly? does that mean i would have to store my user password in my php code? it seems that the tokens i can create for my user on the developer site are only temporary .. thanks!

Comment: No, what you do is direct a user to a page to login, they login, send a code back to you, you exchange that code for a token, and it's done. Read the Facebook page on OAuth or Authentication.

Comment: Ah, but I don't want different users to do this. This is my blog site, and every time i post a blog i want it to post to my facebook page. So it will always post to the same page ... my page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get user_id by this piece of code: `$user_id = $facebook->getUser();`

The first thing you need, is to login an user through a URL returned by `$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => array('perm', 'perm2')))`.

Also, notice, where I put permissions, which I require. Not into the Facebook class constructor, but into the method `getLoginUrl`.

And lastly, for posting into a page, you need `publish_actions` permission (not `publish_stream`).